# How to retain data while using ScopedModel in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

I am using [ScopedModel](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) to fetch some data from a Firebase database.

I am fetching a list of events.

1. I fetch the events from the endpoint inside the Model;
2. I store the events into a `List<Event>` inside the model;
3. I use that list to build my `ListView`.

```
mixin EventModel on Model {
    List<Event> _events = [];

    Future<http.Response> fetchEvents() async {
          http.Response response = await http.get(//Url);

            final List<Event> fetchedEvents = [];

            ... // decode response data into fetchedEvents

            // Add the loaded data to my List
            _events = fetchedEvents;
            notifyListeners();

            ...
      }

}
```

So, when opening the `EventsPage` the first thing I do is to fetch the data in `initState()`.

```
class _EventPageState extends State<EventPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      widget.model.fetchEvents();
    }
  }
}
```

After fetching the network data, my `List` inside my app has the network data so I can use it to build my `ListView`.

**EventsPage.dart**

```
Widget _buildListView(MainModel model) {
    return Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ItemEventBig(model.events[index], index);
        },
        itemCount: model.events.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```

My problem is that, if I navigate to another page and then come back to `EventsPage`, `initState()` will be called again, so `fetchEvents`. Making the app reload all the events list again.

I would like to retain the downloaded data while my app is alive, so If the user go and come back to `EventsPage` the data will not be lost.

I was used to do it in Android using `ViewModel`, how to do it in Flutter?

I want to keep using `ScopedModel` to do my State Management in Flutter.

**Possible Solution**

I thought that a solution would be to store the events in a `List<Event>` as I am doing. Then, when calling `fetchEvents()` I could first check if my `List<Event>` is not null if so, I don't need to call it again because data was already loaded.

This seems a bad solution for me, especially when I have multiple pages fetching the data. Suppose I load the first one, when I go to the second one it will assume the data was already loaded because `List<Event>` is non null and it will not load again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Flutter Documentation - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html

```
class _EventPageState extends State<EventPage> 
     with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<EventPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      widget.model.fetchEvents();
    }
  }
  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem as it retains the state and does not call `initState()` again when changing tabs. There is a need to put `super.build(context);` in your `build()` method, otherwise, it will display a warning.